# `std::any_cast` returns a copy

Tags: c++, c++17, stdany

I was reading the [documentation for `std::any_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) and I find it strange that the API has the cast either return a value to the held object or a pointer to it.  Why not return a reference?  A copy needs to be made every time the function is called with a non pointer type argument.

I can see that the pointer version of the cast might signal intentions a bit more and might be a bit more clear but why not have the value returned be a reference like this?

```
template<typename ValueType>
ValueType& any_cast(any* operand);
```

instead of

```
template <typename ValueType>
ValueType* any_cast(any* operand);
```

Further it seems like even if you ask for a reference the cast removes the reference and returns a copy to the stored object see the explanations for the return values for function overloads 1-3 here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast

Comment: And what if the input pointer is `nullptr`?  It can't be dereferenced to satisfy a returned reference. I think what you are really asking about is why the overloads of `any_cast` that take a reference as input return a copy instead of a reference as output, isn't that right?

Comment: `any_cast` gives a reference if you tell it to. This is like saying `static_cast` always returns a copy.

Comment: The number of valid pointer values of a given type that can't be referenced depends on one's reading of the standard and that standard's evolution, but it is decidedly greater than 0 since it includes the nullpointer.

Comment: Thinking about it, it seems utterly weird. I guess you or Someone™ will have to look up the original paper or papers, to find the rationale. It doesn't seem very practical, what with exception issue and performance.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I guess so,  I understand that the pointer version can be clearer but I am not sure why none of these casts don't return a reference

Comment: @ildjarn  the documentation states that the cast removes the reference, so if you ask for something like `any_cast<Something&>` you will still get a copy when you pass a reference to an `std::any` object

Comment: @Curious: `any_cast<Something&>` will remove the reference while working on the object internally, but it still returns `Something&` as output.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ah my mistake, that should have been very obvious, don't know how I missed that.  Sorry!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can see a discussion regarding the C++ standard for this here: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/ngSIHzM6kDQ

Note that Boost has defined `any_cast` this way for more than a decade, plus it matches `static_cast` and friends.  So if you want a reference, do this:

```
any_cast<Foo&>(x)
```

The same as you'd do for the older `_cast`s in C++.

Comment: Yeah but this isn't really a cast. The word "cast" here is a misnomer. It's a device to access the contained object.

Comment: But if you take a look at the documentation here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast, the reference is removed, right?

Comment: @Curious: Internally yes, but not in the output, because `std::remove_reference_t` is not applied to the return type. The return type is whatever you ask for in the template parameter.

Comment: Just to sum up, with this function to access the object you have to **explicitly opt in** to get a reference, and otherwise, the default, you get the posssibilities of inefficiency and exception issue. With a reasonable design you would have explicitly do a copy to get a copy. So while this answer tells the facts of the situation, it doesn't answer the question, “***why*** not have the value returned be a reference like this”. I can see no reasonable reason. The similarity to cast notation is an aesthetic issue where I absolutely don't share that silly notion of beauty-in-conformity.